# how to use the jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to use the jquery dialog box with a given size so I wrote :

```
$('#dialog').dialog("option", "width", 600 );
```

But I had an error :

> Cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'option'

So I wrote :

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
$('#dialog').dialog("option", "width", 600 );
```

and it works..

Question 1  : it seems so strange to do like this that I wonder if it has to be done like that ?

Question 2 : if I have several options, let's say 'height', what is the syntax to add it ?

thank you

Comment: This is all in the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  width: 600,
  height:140
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer both of your questions: You can pass in an object as the parameter:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    'width':600,
    'height':700
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can set dialog`width` and other options in its initialization.

Your attempt fails because you are trying to set a property before you instantiate the plugin on the element.

Like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 600
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/SpFdS/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this ..

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 450});
```